# Where to find a more complete documentation for Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

For example, the below get_log method on the driver instance allows me to receive a collection of console log messages. Im wondering why i couldn't find this on the Selenium 4 official documentation. The documentation seems to be very sparse and undetailed. Is there a better alternative then ravaging through the source code? I dont want to be looking at multiple chained function calls in the original source code. Would be a great help thanks.

```
   dc = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
   dc["goog:loggingPrefs"] = {"browser":"INFO"}

   driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options, desired_capabilities=dc)
   driver.get("http://www.thepools.com")

   time.sleep(5)

   for entry in driver.get_log('browser'):
        print(entry)
```

Comment: [It's there in the docs.](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_chrome/selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.html?highlight=get_log#selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver.get_log) Where were you looking?

Comment: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/options/

Comment: But thats a great help! Thanks buddy

Comment: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities

Comment: Hye, do you know where i can find the full set of desired capabilities available?

Comment: Huh. Exploring how the site navigation works, I don't know if the docs I linked are in any way discoverable by navigating Selenium's website - the "Documentation" link on the site goes to entirely different documentation that doesn't seem to have any connection to the page I linked, and the search bar doesn't seem to search the docs I linked either.

Comment: Anyway, capabilities aren't controlled by Selenium, so they mostly aren't documented by Selenium either. You can find Selenium's docs for common capabilities [here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/options/), but for browser-specific capabilities, Selenium links to the browser's own capability documentation.